# React tests not running - pragma and pragmaFrag cannot be set when runtime is automatic

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, pragma

My tests were working fine until recently, and they all still run & pass just fine except the top-level `App` component smoke test.

Test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ToastProvider } from 'react-toast-notifications'
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <ToastProvider>
        <App />
      </ToastProvider>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByText("You'll need to sign in to use this feature.")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The Error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/druserkes/Desktop/zephyrx/zephyrx-dr-dashboard/node_modules/react-toast-notifications/dist/ToastContainer.js: pragma and pragmaFrag cannot be set when runtime is automatic.
    > 1 | 'use strict';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
      4 |   value: true

      at File.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:250:12)
      at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js:138:21)
      at PluginPass.enter (node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/create-plugin.js:163:28)
      at newFn (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:175:21)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
      at NodePath.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:92:31)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:116:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:19)
      at TraversalContext.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
```

Commenting out the `'use strict'` line in file in `node_modules` doesn't change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.